# Access methods as subclass

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I created a class which extends from another class and I want to override  one of the parent functions but I want this function to be private from outside (like protected in Java).
I tried to use protected as it says [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/visibility-modifiers.html) but it doesn't work.
Is it possible with Kotlin?

```
open class YesNoDialog(context: Context, styleRes: Int) : Dialog(context, styleRes) {


protected fun setTexts() {

}
```

}

```
class MultiSelectDialog(context: Context, styleRes: Int):YesNoDialog(context, styleRes) {

}
```

In this example I want to access setTexts from MultiSelectDialog class

Comment: Add your code. This will make more sense about the question cause i can not understand the exact requirement  right now.. On a side note you can not narrow down visibility in method overriding.

Comment: you may try to define the function with `protected` visibility and implement it with the same visibility. 
An  `internal` keyword in Kotlin may help for that too, but it will unlikely to solve the whole issue at the JVM bytecode level

Comment: I tried to use protected as it shows in my question - not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with `protected`, but you also need to add `open` to allow it to be overridden:

```
open class YesNoDialog(context: Context, styleRes: Int) : Dialog(context, styleRes) {
    protected open fun setTexts() {

    }
}

class MultiSelectDialog(context: Context, styleRes: Int) : YesNoDialog(context, styleRes) {
    override fun setTexts() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it works.. I didn't know you can use open with protected together